# Send JSON data from angularJS so Go server can parse into struct

Tags: angularjs, json, go

I use angularJS $resource in my client and want to create a custom PATCH function, where I send data to my GO server. I want to parse the data on my GO server to a struct. I tried to send the data like the code below but the GO server outputs the values as '[object Object]' and generats an error when i try to marshal it. Should the data be included as a query string for PATCH or can it/should it be included in the request body?

```
var UpdateOneSchedule = $resource('/schedules/me/:bkchangeobject', {bkchangeobject:{}},{
    update:{
        method: 'PATCH',
        isArray: false,
    }
});
```

code snippet from my PATCH request

```
            var updateObject = {"title":"value", "description":"value"}
            console.log(updateObject)


            UpdateOneSchedule.update({bkchangeobject:updateObject},
            function(data){
                //on success
            },
            function(httpResponse){
                //on error
                if(httpResponse.status === 409){ //StatusConflict
                    //
                    revertFunc()
                }
            });
```

The go server looks like this

```
func (db *bkDatabase) updateSchedule(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    bkDB := bkDatabase{db.session.Copy()}
    defer bkDB.closeDB()

    //check tokens
    if bkSystem.db.isAuthorized(w, r) {
        param := mux.Vars(r)["bkchangeobject"]
        fmt.Println(param)
        var change_object event

        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(param), &change_object)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("JSON Unmarshal error: %v", err)
        }
        fmt.Println(change_object)


    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to use angularJS $resource, I'm new to angularJS.
But I have achieved something similar, with the following codes:

In my controller I declare the object that will be sent to the server side:

```
$scope.message = {
  From: {
    Email: '',
    Name: ''
  },
  Subject: '',
  Content: ''
}
```

This object is linked to the scope, so it can be filled up by the user.
I also created a service that will send the object to the server side:

```
.service('ContactService', function ($http) {
this.url = 'http://url.toyourwebservice.golang/what/you/want';

this.send = function (contact) {
  return $http.post(this.url, contact);
};
```

});

This way, on the server side I can retrieve the object in the request body:

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
if len(b) != 0 {
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, contact)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // Do whatever you want with contact
}
```

Hope this help!